# How can I add characters to an UILabel animated in iOS with Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uilabel, uiviewanimation

**What I tried**

I created a recursive function that loops over a `NSMutableArray` and ever time will go through this animation blog. This method is called by this code because I thought the problem why the animation on the `UILabel` doesn't work is, that it is not run on the main thread.

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(writeText:) 
                       withObject:_arrayAllLabels 
                    waitUntilDone:YES];
```

The animation has a `completion` block which also checks whether the animation is finished and then moves on to call the same function again. Furthermore I added an additional animation blog but nothing makes it able to add characters to the label smooth.

```
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.5f
                          delay:1.0f
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                     animations:^{

                         //adding next character to text attribute of UILabel                      
                     }  completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                       [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f
                                        animations:^{

                          if ( finished ){
                            [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(writeText:)
                                                   withObject:_arrayAllLabels
                                                waitUntilDone:YES];

                          }
                       } completion:nil];

                     }];
```

**What It looks like**

[image]

**What I found after my search wasn't right**

I have been looking around for a while now and tried to find a question related to my problem but everything I found pointed only into one direction, changing the text of an `UILabel` to another text, no single character

- stackoverflow.com/questions/26402062/changing-the-text-of-a-uilabel-makes-it-reappear-when-using-uiviewkeyframeanimat
- stackoverflow.com/questions/26703501/fade-between-text-in-a-uilabel-with-delay

**Can Somebody help?**

Comment: could this be useful ? https://github.com/tomknig/TOMSMorphingLabel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the setText method of a UILabel is not animatable. `animateWithDuration:completion:` will only animate change in frames, bounds, center, transform... See Apple docs on animation here for the list of animatable property : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/AnimatingViews/AnimatingViews.html

For your problem, you have to forget using `animateWithDuration:completion:` and create the animation yourself, by using a NSTimer for example for executing a addLetter: method every x seconds...

Comment: I ran into such a problem already before but it was long time ago. Now I wasn't sure if I just forgot something (like the mainThread). Wondering if there isn't another way to solve this! But I will have a look at NSTimer! :)

Comment: xD sorry, I just realised you are talking about the `NSTimer`, totally right! That's what happens if you stop using a language for way too long :)